# Array of Objects via JSON and jQuery to Selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I have problems transferring a dataset (array of objects) from a servlet to a jsp/jquery.

This is the dataset sent by the servlet (Json):

```
[
    {aktion:"ac1", id:"26"},
    {aktion:"ac2", id:"1"},
    {aktion:"ac3", id:"16"},
    {aktion:"ac4", id:"2"}
]
```

The jsp:

```
function getSelectContent($selectID) {
alert('test');
 $.ajax({
        url:'ShowOverviewDOC',
        type:'GET',
        data: 'q=getAktionenAsDropdown',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function() {
            alert('Error loading json data!');
        },

    success: function(json){
        var output = '';
        for (p in json) {

    $('#'+$selectID).append($('<option>').text(json[p].aktion).attr('value', json[p].aktion));

}
                    }});

};
```

If I try to run this the Error ('Error loading json data') is alerted. 
Has someone an idea where the mistake may be? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the `error` function is running, then your server is returning an error response (HTTP response code >= 400).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are setting the data parameter looks a bit suspect (notice JSON encoding in my example below). Here is how it would look calling a .Net asmx

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/_layouts/DashboardService.asmx/MinimizeWidgetState",
  data: "{'widgetType':'" + widgetType + "', 'isMinimized':'" + collapsed + "'}"
});
```

Also the return data is by default placed in the .d property of the return variable. You can change this default behavior by adding some ajax setup script.

```
//Global AJAX Setup, sets default properties for ajax calls. Allows browsers to make use of native JSON parsing (if present)
//and resolves issues with certain ASP.NET AJAX services pulling data from the ".d" attribute.
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{}",
    success: function(msg) {
        if (this.console && typeof console.log != "undefined")
            console.log(msg);
    },
    dataFilter: function(data) {
        var msg;

        //If there's native JSON parsing then use it.
        if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' && typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function')
            msg = JSON.parse(data);
        else
            msg = eval('(' + data + ')');

        //If the data is stuck in the "."d" property then go find it.
        if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
            return msg.d;
        else
            return msg;
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        handleAjaxError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To see exactly what is going on, check the textStatus and errorThrown information that is provided by the error callback. That might help narrow it down.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/